# How to get the calendar event for a day in the future on Android device;

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

How to get the calendar event for a day in the future on Android device;

Because it was inserted using recursive rules like

```
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=5");
```

So,when i need get the calendar event for a day in the future,i must compare whit each rules?

Is there any other convenient way?

Comment: The official API is provided. In the CalendarContract.Instances, I am stupid.

Answer (score 1):

The official API is provided. In the CalendarContract.Instances

https://developer.android.google.cn/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider#query-instances